# jQuery UI autocomplete widget dropdown styling is not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

When i hover over the items on autocomplete dropdown, background-color is not changing, it's still white.
I am using this styling in site.css:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.ui-autocomplete > li {
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-state-focus {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}
```

BundleConfig code:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                       "~/Content/Site.css"
                      ));
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: I am using this widget on a Bootstrap input text

Comment: try `!important`, better try adding an `id` selector

Comment: @TJ I tried `!important` but still not working :/